# How to cancel http request in react-redux epic

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, rxjs, axios, observable

I would like to cancel an http request that I call inside an redux epic. My http request uses axios which can provide a cancel token... 
But if i create the cancel token, where do I use it?

I turned my http request into an observable using rxjs/from and I use takeUntil from rxjs to unsubscribe from the http request... but does this truly "cancel" my http request? How do I ensure the http request is actually cancelled? Don't I have to use the cancel token?

```
const loadApplicationNotesEpic: Epic<Action, Action, RootState> = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(actions.getApplicationNotes)),
    map(action => action.payload),
    switchMap(applicationId => {
       // create cancel token here?: 
       // const cancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
       // where to use cancelToken?
      return from(axios.get(apiUrl(`/${applicationId}/notes`))).pipe(
        takeUntil(filterAction(action$, actions.getApplicationNotesCancel)),
        map(notes => actions.getApplicationNotesSuccess(notes, applicationId)),
        catchError(error => {
          console.error(error);
          return of(actions.getApplicationNotesError(error));
        }),
      );
    }),
  );
```

Comment: Would you want to _race_ between `from(..)` and `filterAction(action$, actions.getApplicationNotesCancel)` rather than `from().takeUntil()`?

Comment: @chautelly ..hmm I'm not too clear about what you mean by race? I know that I specifically want to use `takeUntil` specifically for the `from(axiosFunction)` observable

Comment: Why do you want to use _takeUntil_ specifically? The observable returned by _from_ only emits 1 event.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is racing between the promise fulfilling or the cancel action being dispatched. This would allow you to check which of the 2 won the race and in case of the cancellation you would call the appropriate function to inform axios?

Comment: @chautelly hmm... okay that makes sense i will definitely give it a try! I'm a little new to rxjs and didn't realize race was an option

Comment: No worries, I'm new-ish to RxJS as well!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I think you might be looking for. I'm not familiar with *axios*. I just plucked the cancellation example from their website.

I also replaced `switchMap` with `mergeMap` because I think that if another action is emitted by

```
..
    filter(isActionOf(actions.getApplicationNotes)),
    map(action => action.payload),
..
```

Then it would cancel the subscription to the previous observable returned by *switchMap* without necessarily cancelling the call to `axios.get`

```
const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
const source = CancelToken.source();

const loadApplicationNotesEpic: Epic<Action, Action, RootState> = action$ =>
  action$.pipe(
    filter(isActionOf(actions.getApplicationNotes)),
    map(action => action.payload),
    mergeMap(applicationId => {
      // create cancel token here?:
      // const cancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
      // where to use cancelToken?

      const promise$ = from(
        axios.get(
          apiUrl(`/${applicationId}/notes`, { cancelToken: source.token })
        )
      ).pipe(
        catchError(error => {
          console.error(error);
          return of(actions.getApplicationNotesError(error));
        })
      );

      const cancelled$ = filterAction(
        action$,
        actions.getApplicationNotesCancel
      ).pipe(mapTo("cancelled"));

      return race(promise$, cancelled$).pipe(
        mergeMap(winner => {
          if (winner === "cancelled") {
            return of(EMPTY).pipe(
                     tap(() => source.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.')),
                     ignoreElements())
          }

          return of(winner).pipe(
            map(notes =>
              actions.getApplicationNotesSuccess(notes, applicationId)
            )
          );
        })
      );
    })
  );
```